# How to use Intel controller to run Kali GUI

Tags: kali-linux, gdm, xorg.conf

I've gone through many tips and different steps at this point, and the Kali GUI will still not run.

In fact, after installing bumblebee and configuring and restarting, my Kali goes straight to the tty.

I believe the problem lies in the fact that the system is now trying to use my NVidia card to render the GUI, but determines that the card is not VGA compatible.

However, as I understand it now, the onboard Intel controller is considered the default VGA renderer. How would I go about configuring Xorg, Bumblebee conf files, etc. to install graphics setup correctly so I can finally start running the Kali GUI?

I will mention that I have NVidia-kernel-dkms and all other tools recommended to run an NVidia, per the Kali docs and BlackMoreOps.

By the way, I have an Asus 501L, with an NVidia GTX 950M.

Segmentation fault doesn't appear when I don't have my Xorg config file. Instead, the screen flickers madly with multiple tearing displays when I enter the tty.

UPDATE:

I managed to switch to the Intel GPU in xorg.conf, but I also enabled UXA hardware acceleration. Interestingly that is not what appears to be going on in the message log.

**Xorg Configuration**

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor0"
    VendorName      "Unknown"
    ModelName       "Unknown"
    HorizSync        28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh      43.0 - 72.0
    Option          "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "intelgpu0"
    Driver          "intel"
    VendorName      "Intel Corporation"
    Option          "AccelMethod" "UXA"
    Option          "TearFree" "true"
    BusID           "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "nvidia"
    Driver          "nvidia"
    VendorName      "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID           "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "intelgpu0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

---

[Message Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XcfIQGBkDLdDVTRnhoRzFlZ1dISkZGMjRhOWdTLXVmSzhz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried to install the nvidia drivers for Linux?  It is easy enough to do and it may very well fix your issue with x not starting.

Comment: Also are you running Kali from a live cd/DVD/usb or is it installed on a hard drive?

Comment: @Richie086 it's a hard drive install. I've tried both the open source installation steps from the Kali Sana repo and then uninstalled and installed the closed-source. Interestingly, that and the closed-source give the same result (hanging at [ OK ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.)

Comment: By closed source do you mean the drivers from nvidia?  That's always how I would install the drivers.   It's a little bit of a PITA to do, but never had any issues installing them.   Are you running the installer as root or are you using Sudo to install?

Comment: @Richie086 I'm running the install as root. Yes- the latest attempt was with installing the driver from NVidia. Yet the output is the same in Xorg.0.log- "No devices detected" and "no screens found." I've followed instructions to allow the video card to be found at its PCI address in Xorg.conf and even added the Intel controller to the device list, still no dice. I downloaded Bumblebee too- if I could I could "optirun" the gdm3 service but of course that's reserved for applications...

Comment: Hmm interesting. You are not getting the "no screens found error", you are getting a segmentation fault.  When you originally installed Kali, was the gui available in the installer?

Comment: You mean was there an option for Graphical Install? Yes, but a friend of mine (who was much more familiar with Linux than I was) chose a different install option to ensure Kali would install on LUKS encrypted partitions.

Comment: Also my friend was manually mapping LVMs and Volume Groups. He was much more into this than I was.

Comment: @Richie086 I had a lot of assistance in setting this up. I'm convinced the segmentation fault had something to do with not mapping to the correct address of Intel's integrated GPU I have on board.

Comment: @Richie086 hey man, anymore news? I tried configuring Xorg to use the Intel chip finally. I have the classic "Oh no!" screen with larger dimensions on my screen, and I'm using UXA acceleration since SNA acceleration causes the tty to flicker and tear

Comment: Is reinstalling the OS an option at all?  Segmentation faults are sort of the Linux equivalent of a BSOD in Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33603/discussion-between-kieran-ojakangas-and-richie086).

Comment: @Richie086 hey man, I found something new, check the images in the question when you can.

Comment: @Richie086 Hey man, whenever you are ready, I am ready to move forward. I said I was considering moving forward in the installation without you but I really don't want to screw this up :P so I'll have a way to know that you get back. Got my Stack Exchange app for when you visit this thread... if and when you do.

Comment: Sorry man I got really sick with the flu. It will be another day at least until I am back to being able to think clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry! Get better. I have other things to take care of- I'm happy to wait until you get yourself up and running again.

Comment: Cool I'll let you know.

Comment: @Riche086 and everyone else... an update... I purged almost ALL of my nvidia files, and restored nouveau and the GUI works! The interesting thing, too, is that I don't get nouveau's SCHED_ERROR line like I usually did when I load the first version of Kali. The ONLY thing is that only one resolution appears to be detected in my hard drive install, and it hardly fits my screen. :(

Comment: You should be able to set the resolution in xorg.conf

Comment: Cool, how would I do that?

Comment: Look up xorg.config examples online and you will find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to getting your xorg.conf file to set the resolution of the GUI, try this

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync       30.0-62.0
    VertRefresh     50.0-70.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
    Device        "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth    24
        Modes     "1024x768" "800x600"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

change the Modes "1024x768" "800x600" to whatever video modes you want to be your possible video mode resolutons.   Be sure to reboot your machine after making this change to xorg.conf tho.   I would also backup xorg.conf before you make these edits by doing

```
sudo cp xorg.conf xorg.conf.backup
```

in the /etc/ directory of course

Comment: Did that work to change the resolution?